# Number of ways to put $N$ balls into $M$ bags so that number of balls is in non-increasing order

Tags: combinatorics

Let $N,M\in \mathbb{N}^+$. What are the number of ways to distribute $N$ unlabeled balls into $M$ labeled bags so that the number of balls in each bag satisfies $N_1 \geq N_2 \geq \dots \geq N_m$?
Finding a general formula for any $N,M\in\mathbb{N}^+$ is desired. If that couldn't be done, solving for the case where $N \geq M $ is also good.

Comment: What you're asking about is the number of partitions of $N$ into at most $M$ parts. [Partitions of Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Restricted_part_size_or_number_of_parts) is a whole branch of number theory: I don't know much about it, but I believe closed formulas are available only for fixed and very small values of $M$.

Comment: For $M=3$ it's OEIS sequence [A0001399](http://oeis.org/A001399).

Comment: @bof $M$ is a fixed number here so it's not an "at most" problem. I'm asking how many different partitions there are which satisfies a certain condition.Without that condition it's easy to solve using start and bar methods.

Comment: **Compositions** of numbers can easily be counted by the "stars and bars" method. **Partitions** of numbers lead to much deeper mathematics. The number of partitions of $n$ into **exactly** $k$ parts is the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$ where the $x_i$ are integers and $x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots\ge x_k\gt0$. The number of partitions of $n$ into **at most** $k$ parts is the number of solutions of $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k=n$ where the $x_i$ are integers and $x_1\ge x_2\ge\cdots\ge x_k\ge0$. See the Wikipedia page I referred you to in my first comment for more details.

Comment: In your problem, can some bags be empty? If there can be empty bags, it's the "at most" problem; in ounting the number of "parts" in a partition, we only count the nonempty bags.

Comment: @bof Thank you for that. The bags indeed can be empty and it should be an "at most" partition problem. You said that partition problems can't be solved by stars and bars, but isn't the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+..+x_k = n$, where all $x_i$'s are integers, simply $n+k-1 \choose n$?

Comment: Yes, but those solutions are [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) rather than partitions. In a composition, the order of the summands matters; $2+1$ and $1+2$ are two different compositions of $3$. In a partition the order does not matter, and the summands are conventionally listed in non-increasing order: $2+1$ and $1+2$ are the same partition of $3$, standardly written in the form $2+1$. The number of **unrestricted** partitions of $n$ is the partition function: $p(0)=p(1)=1,p(2)=2,p(3)=3,p(4)=5,p(5)=7,p(6)=11, . . .$ http://oeis.org/A000041